# apache mod_rewrite for let's encrypt not redirecting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, lets-encrypt

I am writing an vhost to allow lets encrypt to access file via http and any other request requested to https

here my full vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@{{ domain_name }}
    ServerName {{ domain_name }}
    ServerAlias {{ domain_name }}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/letsencrypt

    <Directory /var/www/letsencrypt>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond ^/.well-known/acme-challenge$ [NC]
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I comment my RewriteCond I got redirected to https but I can't make my RewriteCond work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vhost conf was containing two mistakes, one on the `RewriteCond` and one on the position of the rewrite in the conf.

here the functioning one :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@{{ domain_name }}
    ServerName {{ domain_name }}
    ServerAlias {{ domain_name }}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/letsencrypt

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/letsencrypt>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-http-{{ domain_name }}.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-http-{{ domain_name }}.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```